# NameError (uninitialized constant Stripe::Payout)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Following the stripe doc https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts to make bank transfers/payouts to accounts from our platform, I got the next error

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Stripe::Payout)
```

I'm  using 
    gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
    gem 'stripe', '~> 2.0'

And the code with in the controller is

```
transfer = Stripe::Payout.create(
{
 :amount => ((invoice.total - invoice.fee)*100).to_i,
 :currency => "usd"
},
{:stripe_account => @event.admin.stripe_user_id}
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade to [at least version 2.2.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/master/History.txt) of the Stripe Ruby library in order to use Payouts.